# Load html document in javascript from text

Tags: javascript, html, dom, load, document

Is it possible to load an html document into a DOM javascript object so that you can read the elements in the document? For example, if I have a file on the server Test.html. Can the page Hello.html call javascript code to load Test.html into a DOM object?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can issue an AJAX request to the new page and get the result as HTML. Then you can bind the HTML to the DOM element.

If you can use a javascrpt library like jQuery there is a load method which loads the data from server and place the returned HTML in a DOM object.

See **[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

```
$('yourselector').load('Test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#where_to_paste").load('Test.html');
```